# How does Google Analytics track page time with an iOS Browser switching Apps?

Tags: ios, statistics, google-analytics

This is a conundrum.

I know that Google Analytics determines page time by the following:

```
User Visits Page 1

User Visits Page 2: 12 Seconds later
```

So the user spent 12 seconds on page 1.

But consider the following:

```
User is on ipad

User visits Page 1

User switches to another App (Angry Birds)

User plays angry birds for 20 minutes

User switches back to Browser

User Visits Page 2: 21 Minutes later
```

Would Google Analytics state that user was on page 1 for 21 minutes? Or is there something in GA or iOS that prevents that?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum time is 30 minutes. After that time, the GA cookie expires.
So in your case, after 21 minutes you would still be in the same session.

See: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsCookies.html

[EDIT - after comment]

Safari will not reload the current page, as long as the Safari App is still open. So in this case, the session will simply continue as if you never left Safari.

If for memory reasons, iOS shuts down the Safari app, it will reload the last page upon start which will create a new page view on the page in GA and the page time count will start again.

So, in essence, you can't really say...

Comment: Thank you for the response, but not the answer I was looking for.  I understand about the 30 minute cookie -- my question is that since the browser is no longer "loaded" -- ie another app has been selected -- does the session reset when the user "goes back" to the browser.